# How do I get Phpmyadmin to work with Nginx and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and Nginx.

I want to install phpmyadmin and have access to it on mydomain.com/phpmyadmin.

I've looked around and I see some ways to get it to work, but not in the way mentioned above. I'm sure it's simple to do, but I'm a complete server noob atm.

**Edit:**

Nevermind, I found out an easy way to do it.

I just created a symbolic link from my phpmyadmin folder into my public web folder. I did this before but I didn't clear the cache so I thought it didn't work.

For Ubuntu 11.04 users with the default nginx file path, here are the steps:

1) ln -sf /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/www

2) /etc/init.d/nginx restart

3) delete your browser cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to configure php with fpm or fastcgi (older method) on nginx, there are plenty of docs available for that.
Once you have setup php with either of the methods, all you have to do is extract phpmyadmin files to the docroot in a subdirectory and configure phpmyadmin by editing config.inc.php or using the setup script provided at /setup.

To setup php 5.3 fpm + nginx: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian

Comment: I already have FastCGI installed, and the phpmyadmin setup doesn't have an option to choose nginx, only apache or lighttpd. There's also no option in the config.inc.php file to change the setting to what I want.

Comment: Well, I have nginx and phpmyadmin running already, and I used the pma setup script. I distinctly remember pma setup script supporting only apache or lighttpd. Which setup script are you talking about?

Comment: The script that automatically ran when I did apt-get install phpmyadmin. It asked me which web server I ran: apache or lighttpd, so I pressed esc since I only use nginx.

Comment: That's not the script I'm talking about. This script is web based located at <pma-root>/setup. This has to be launched using the browser after php has been configured on nginx.

Comment: I found the folder: what's the script name and how do I launch it with a web browser? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I've been yelling all over it is located at <pma-root>/setup. Just go to your browser and type http://address/phpmyadmin/setup